# Retrieve variable value from flash

Tags: c#, flash, actionscript-3, variables, get

I have an `AxShockwaveFlash` object in a Windows Forms application, and load a (AS3) movie into it with `LoadMovie`. The movie plays correctly, but I am having a problem getting a variable from flash.

I have tried using `GetVariable` but it always returns an empty string. How can I get the value of a variable from flash?

Comment: Do you have access to the Flash's source?

Comment: @Adam no, it's an arbitrary flash video. A youtube video atcually, from `youtube.com/v/whatever`

Comment: @Seth So what variable are you trying to get out of the Flash?

Comment: @Adam `_level0.list`, `_level0.title`, `_level0.sk`,  and `_level0.video_id` :)

Comment: @Seth A AVM2 SWF (made with ActionScript3) does not use _level0 anymore. That is an old AVM1 (AS2) thing. You might be able to access these variable using the root.loaderInfo.parameters object instead, but I have never done this before, so untested.

Comment: @Adam how do I get at `root.loaderInfo.parameters` from C#?

Comment: @Seth Sorry but I am not sure about that. I was just making sure you are trying to get the correct vars. Maybe take a look here: http://bojordan.com/log/?p=269

Comment: @Adam nope, doesn't say how to get a variable. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the new security policy for AVM2 requires you to explicitly expose the variables/functions to the container application using ExternalInterface.

If you can't edit the swf, I can't think of a way to get access to them. It was really easy with AS2 though, if you defined it, you could get and set it via javascript/C#/whatever without any extra code in the swf.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use `fscommand` method to talk to C# from shockwave player:

```
fscommand("sendCmd", arg);
```

to catch value in C# use

```
flashPlayer.FSCommand += new AxShockwaveFlashObjects._IShockwaveFlashEvents_FSCommandEventHandler(flashPlayer_FSCommand);
....
void flashPlayer_FSCommand(object sender, AxShockwaveFlashObjects._IShockwaveFlashEvents_FSCommandEvent e)
{
    tbOut.Text += e.command + " (" + e.args + ")" + "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: This won't work, because as mentioned in the question comments, it is using a pre-compiled SWF, so no way to add the fscommand code in ActionScript.